# What is the maximum tuple array size in Python 3?

Tags: python, tuples, limits

I am building a web scraper that stores data retrieved from four different websites into a tuple array. I later iterate through the tuple and save the entire lot as both CSV and Excel.
Are tuple arrays or arrays in general, limited to the processor's RAM/disc-space?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html), this is given by `sys.maxsize`

> sys.**maxsize**
>
> An integer giving the maximum value a variable of type Py_ssize_t can
>   take. It’s usually `2**31 - 1` on a 32-bit platform and `2**63 - 1` on a
>   64-bit platform.

And interestingly enough, this the Python3 doc about data model gives more implementation details under [`object.__len__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__).

> **CPython implementation detail:** In CPython, the length is required to
>   be at most `sys.maxsize`. If the length is larger than sys.maxsize
>   some features (such as `len()`) may raise `OverflowError`.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the maxsize class. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I believe tuples and lists are limited by the size of the machine's virtual memory, unless you're on a 32 bit system in which case you're limited by the small word size.  Also, lists are dynamically resized by...  I believe about 12% each time they grow too small, so there's a little overhead there as well.

If you're concerned you're going to run out of virtual memory, it might be a good idea to write to a file or files instead.